# i cant understand this jquery code

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
        // Left arrow key pressed
        case 37:
            $('img').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
            break;
        // Up Arrow Pressed
        case 38:
            $('img').animate({top: "-=10px"},'fast');
            break;
        // Right Arrow Pressed
        case 39:
            $('img').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
            break;
        // Down Array Pressed
        case 40:
            $('img').animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
            break;
    }
});
});
```

1. why he put key in keydown(function(key)  what this key do and can i put any thing in
2. parseInt ?
3. switch(parseInt(key.which,10))

Comment: Have you attempted to google these questions? Most have pretty straight forward answers just from their definitions alone.

Answer (score 1):

1. keydown(function(key)) is a javascript function detecting key press from your keyboard. key is just a name he gave to the variable.
2. parseInt is parsing the received value to a number (integer)
3. Switch upon value of key, 10 is just numbering system he uses - there is binary (1's and 0's), hexadecimal (numbers of 0-10 and letters A-F) etc, he uses standard numbering system, which is characters from 0-9 that make up "normal" numbers. Upon switching he decides whats is going to happen on any given button press. Example list of such character codes can be found here http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: I am sorry but I am a  beginner in jqery   why he put key in function    i need more explane and   switch(parseInt(key.which,10))

Comment: because he wanted some action to happen when given key was pressed on the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

When someone press any key in his keyboard, it will trigger a event and call that bind($(document).keydown). Which will receive a event object.
That object has a ASCII code of which key was pressed(event.which).
So that function just wait for some event to occur and parse which key was pressed and map it to animate the "img".

Comment: When someone press a key(keyboard), or just click anywhere; ocur a event that propague though the DOM and reach "document".

What he did was;

    $(document).ready // intercept the event(document rendered, loaded, etc.) and calls the function.
    $(document).keydown // when someone press any keyboard key, the param function is called with a event object(he named it "key")

that event object has a param "which" that indicate which key was pressed.
He than animated the img based on which key was pressed.